# QML: move to next control in form

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

How can I move focus from one control to next one inside QML form?
By default it works with `Tab` button but I need to change it to `Enter`.
All the control are ordered with `Gridlayout` with 2 columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've defined a new component, TextFieldMoveOnReturn.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

TextField {
    Keys.onReturnPressed:  nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
}
```

If you use this one instead of TextField, you get the required behaviour

*edit* a better solution: define a new component GridLayoutNextOnReturn.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

GridLayout {
    Keys.onReturnPressed: {
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; ++i)
            if (children[i].focus) {
                children[i].nextItemInFocusChain().forceActiveFocus()
                break
            }
    }
}
```

and use normal TextField inside - works like a charm

Comment: This is much more flexible (specifically the second approach) than the other answers, and it seems like you've addressed your own concerns that you mentioned in the comments for Simon's answer?

Comment: Yes, actually I tried to show with a working example why the approach of that answer was not so good. BTW, in this case it turns out that QML have a solution 'ready to go', but I had experience - in video handling - of code not working portably between Linux and Android. And has been difficult for me to code a workaround...

Comment: No, I didn't considered to report it. My workaround it's fairly complicated, but anyway allowed me to go on... I'm used to think that I don't really understand a platform if I'm not able to overcome problems I find. Actually, I was hoping that QML could be an easy path to declarative C++... It's not really easy, but it's the better I know by now.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the right way to do it. It makes the keyboard close rand reopen and 2 of my devices and as a consequence the keyboard layout is reset to english. But when I press Enter/Next in native apps or web forms keyboard stays open and keyboard layout isn't changed. I wonder how I can achieve the same in QML.

Comment: @Sassan: I tested on Ubuntu, a desktop device. Alas, with time passing and releases flowing,  now I'm unable to run the Android toolkit and test your issue. It's worth further study though.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it more robust and flexible, you should make same behaviour
for `Tab` and `Enter/Return` keys.
Handle `keyPressed` event and use `KeyNavigation.tab` instead of `nextItemInFocusChain` to focus next element as follow:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.12

Column {
    TextField {
        id: field1
        KeyNavigation.tab: field2
        activeFocusOnTab: true
        Keys.onReturnPressed: KeyNavigation.tab.forceActiveFocus();
    }
    TextField {
        id: field2
        KeyNavigation.tab: field3
        activeFocusOnTab: true
        Keys.onReturnPressed: KeyNavigation.tab.forceActiveFocus();
    }
    TextField {
        id: field3
        KeyNavigation.tab: field1
        activeFocusOnTab: true
        Keys.onReturnPressed: KeyNavigation.tab.forceActiveFocus();
    }
}
```

So you controlled order of focus and users can use both `tab` and `return` keys interchangeably which results ***better UX***.
Whenever you want to ***change order***, just change `KeyNavigation.tab` values :)

**Note:** I extremely suggest you to avoid using `nextItemInFocusChain` because of future changes and flexibility

Comment: Clever solution, works better than other answers and it's quite flexible

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onEditingFinished](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#editingFinished-signal):

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2

        Label {
            text: "Name"
        }
        TextField {
            onEditingFinished: addressEdit.focus = true
        }
        Label {
            text: "Address"
        }
        TextField {
            id: addressEdit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you add a 3rd field and click in the 1st when editing the 2nd, both the 1st and the 3rd are focussed.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for. However, can you share the faulty code that you're talking about?

Comment: Right, but that is a bug in Qt: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-40145 The code you linked to will work when that is fixed. `forceActiveFocus()` isn't really necessary.

Comment: Well, right. If focus worked properly, `forceActiveFocus()` is the same as setting `focus = true` because the parent focus scope has active focus. Thx for filing that bug report. But `onEditingFinished` is still not what OP wants because it is also triggered when the mouse leaves to any previous input field.

Comment: True, he didn't mention mouse clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Keys.onReturnPressed` and `forceActiveFocus()`

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2

        Label {
            text: "Name"
        }
        TextField {
            Keys.onReturnPressed: organizationEdit.forceActiveFocus()
        }
        Label {
            text: "Organization"
        }
        TextField {
            id: organizationEdit
            Keys.onReturnPressed: addressEdit.forceActiveFocus()
        }
        Label {
            text: "Address"
        }
        TextField {
            id: addressEdit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming this kind of code it's the proper way to solve OP problem make me wonder about how much we loose 'evolving' UX from Qt C++ to QML

Comment: @CapelliC: "this kind of code"? What do you lose between C++ and QML here? The C++ equivalent is actually more code to write (even more if you use .h and .cpp files): http://pastebin.com/HHy4DQ9W

Comment: @Mitch: what I miss it's the ability to override elements **behaviour**, so to be able to provide different UX, retaining the declarative, reusable interface. Would do you suggest to override QML GridLayout ? You translated the QML 'solution' in C++, but I would search for a more declarative way - maybe already provided from QDialog or QWidget... If it's not already provided, in C++ I know how to implement it. But in QML ?

Comment: @CapelliC: What do you mean by "override QML GridLayout"? What are you actually trying to achieve (in terms of a tangible problem)?

Comment: @Mitch: by myself, I'm not currently in trouble with this. We are commenting OP's problem, no ? Anyway, I had some experience overriding QML elements - in QML - and I found it's not an easy task. Mostly 'programming by try-and-see if it works'...

Comment: @CapelliC: Haha, you can't make an off topic comment about C++ vs QML and then claim that we're discussing the OP's problem. No one has any idea what your specific issue is, so it's even more pointless to bring it up here.

Comment: Well this is not just weird off-topic philosophy, he has a good point there. My solution above might work but is still bad code style. For example the fixed connection between field ids does not allow you to easily add or move one field. You could hack around that and get the successor's id automatically but that does further decrease readability.

Comment: Thanks, @CapelliC! The `nextItemInFocusChain` really was something new for me. Actually it what I was looking for ) Basically, all the solutions are similar to it; 
Thanks for all the participants, your comments guys helped me to see another side of the problem.